# Contact without name causes app to crash on iPhone

Tags: swift, addressbook, abaddressbook

I am trying to retrieve contact names, here's how:

```
func getContactNames() {
  let adbk : ABAddressBook? = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()

  let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(adbk).takeRetainedValue() as [ABRecord]
    for person in people {
        contactList.append(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue() as String)
    }
}
```

When all contacts do have names it works, although when there are some contacts without names, app crashes and I get:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I tried using `?` like this:

```
let contact2 = (ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String)
 if contact2 != nil {
   contactList.append(contact2!)
 }
```

Then I would always get `nil`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about why you always get `nil`, but I would recommend more Swift-style checking whether Optional is nil or not. Do it like that: `if let contact2 = (ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String){
      contactList.append(contact2)
    }`

Comment: That's exactly what happens if you have optional values and you are not checking that they are optional: It will crash. That's the idea and purpose of optional values, to crash when the programmer is careless instead of giving weird results. If you have an optional value and it isn't present, you have to check for that.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you have to do it step-by-step: first check if `ABRecordCopyCompositeName`is not `nil` and then take it and convert to string.

```
if let tmpName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person) {
   let contact2 = tmpName.takeRetainedValue() as String
   contactList.append(contact2)
}
```